# Enviar un correo con registros en un ciclo for

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, phpexcel

Buen día , tengo este problema me gustaría recibir ideas para poder realizar esto correctamente.

El tema de esto es que utilizo un modulo para subir un excel y cargar los registros que se encuentran dentro de el con ello no tengo problema.
dichos registros cuando se envían hacen una comparación y buscan un campo llamado "RFC" donde hace la búsqueda para encontrar los rfc a actualizar

mi variable $rfc es la variable donde hará la búsqueda de los rfc que existen $valor_a_actualizar es solo un ejemplo de mis variables que mando en este caso lo tomaremos como solo 1 variable que actualizara

**estados.php**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $array_num; ++$i){
  $rfc=$data[$i][2];
  $valor_a_actualizar=$data[$i][2];
  func::updateCustomerExcel($dbh, $rfc);
}
```

En este for solamente envio todos los registros que tengo en el excel y lo envio a una funcion PDO donde actualizara todos los rfc que encuentre

**Funcion**

```
   public static function updateCustomerExcel($dbh,$rfc,$valor_a_actualizar)
          {
            $query = "UPDATE proveedores SET columna=:valor
            WHERE rfc=:rfc";
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute(array(':valor' => $valor_a_actualizar),
            ':rfc' => strtoupper($rfc)));
```

**En este punto hago una busqueda solo para
 atraer los datos de los correos relacionados con 
ese rfc en otras tablas**

```
   $query = "SELECT count(pv.id) as total, pv.id,up.usuario_id as usuario, 
   up.proveedor_id as proveedor, us.correo FROM `proveedores` pv
   INNER JOIN proveedores up ON pv.id = up.proveedor_id
   INNER JOIN estatus esp ON pv.estatus_id = esp.id
   INNER JOIN tipos tp ON pv.tipo_id = tp.id
   INNER JOIN usuarios us ON up.usuario_id = us.id where pv.rfc =:rfcbusca";
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute(array(':rfcbusca' => strtoupper($rfc)));
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Como resultado obtengo 1 correo
example@example.com

**Aqui es donde esta el problema**
Tengo este ciclo para enviar un correo donde habra un mensaje que dira que registros del rfc se han actualizado el detalle aqui es que cuando leo 2 registros me envian 2 correos , ¿Como hacer para enviar una lista de usuarios que se han actualizado en un correo solo?

```
            for ($i=0; $i < $row['total'] ; $i++) {
              $email = $row['correo'];
              $nombre = "usuario actualizado";
              $asunto = "usuario actualizado 2";
              $row['rfc'];
              $cuerpo = "<br/>Se actualizo el estado del cliente: ".$row['rfc']."<br/>Paso hacer : ".$row['estatus']."<br/>";
              func::enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo);
            }
```

> Agradezco por su colaboración

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Nombre, asunto y cuerpo no deberian ir afuera del for? (ya que son siempre lo mismo), asi mismo, enviar no deberia estar afuera tambien?

Comment: o sea, no deberias solo concatenar la variable $email con tantos email como quieras enviar?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que ese ciclo for despliego  una lista de correo y lo que quiero hacer es desplegar dentro de ese ciclo una lista de rfc que se actualisaron solo para enviar un correo , me explico?

Comment: entonces cuerpo tambien deberia ir dentro del for. Fijate que tu for hace enviarEmail en todas las vueltas. .que es justo lo que queres evitar. no?

Comment: Asi es deberia tambien de ir dentro el cuerpo